# Select2 allowclear and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use select2 and knockoutJs with this simple binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()) || {};
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).select2(options);
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Markup:

```
<select class="select2" style="width:100%" data-bind="optionsCaption: '',options: $root.items,optionsText: 'description',optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.selectedItem,select2: { placeholder: 'Select an item...',allowClear: true }"></select>
```

it works! Now I enabled the `allowClear` option in Select2 to clear dropdown to a placeholder value like `Select an item...`.

If I click the `x` icon dropdown properly sets the placeholder but knockout don't update observable binded value!

I think I've to change custombinding adding something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(element).select2(options).on("select2-removed", function (e) {
       ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function () { return ''; });
    });
...
```

but it won't work!

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle with your code

Comment: What's with the setTimeout? Also, I can see only "init" implementation, can you show your "update" implementation in bindingHandler as well, if you have one?

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues.

1) the `update` in bindinghandler is to **update DOM based on value change**, you should never define an `update` callback with the ability to mutate your model.

The right way is, when define a new bindinghandler, use `init` callback to hook up all `change` events with the model, the `update` callback is merely a **DOM drawing routine**.

If your `init` provided DOM drawing (such as provided by select2), you don't need to define an `update` callback.

Hence the line `ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function () { return ''; });` only redraw the DOM, it doesn't do what you want.

2) the `select2` binding you created has some holes.

- first, `value` binding doesn't know the existence of `select2` binding, that's where you struggled.
- second, your `select2` binding has to wait for other binding (the `options` binding) to finish DOM creation, what's why you use `setTimeout`. But ko provided a way to define sequence of the bindings, just look the source code of `ko value` binding, it's defined as `'after': ['options', 'foreach']`
- third, your select2 doesn't respond to outside change. For instance, if you have another UI to update `$root.selectedItem` (a normal select list), the change raised by that UI would not sync back to your select2.

**The solution**

Define `select2` binding <strike>based on existing `value` binding</strike> (just found out it's not needed), and hook up all change events.

- we don't need `"select2-removed"` event, it's all about `"change"` event.
- `select2` provided all drawing, we don't need `update` callback.
- use a flag `shouldIgnore` to break the loop between value subscriber and select2 change event handler.

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/huocp/8N3zX/6/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/huocp/8N3zX/9/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueSelect2 = {
    'after': ['options'],
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // kind of extend value binding
        // ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);

        var options = allBindings.get('select2Options') || {};
        $(element).select2(options);

        var value = valueAccessor();
        // init val
        $(element).val(ko.unwrap(value)).trigger("change");

        var changeListener;
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            var shouldIgnore = false;
            changeListener = value.subscribe(function(newVal) {
                if (! shouldIgnore) {
                  shouldIgnore = true;
                  // this is just select2 syntax
                  $(element).val(newVal).trigger("change");
                  shouldIgnore = false;
                }
            });

            // this demo only works on single select.
            $(element).on("change", function(e) {
                if (! shouldIgnore) {
                    shouldIgnore = true;
                    if (e.val == '') {
                        // select2 use empty string for unselected value
                        // it could cause problem when you really want '' as a valid option
                        value(undefined);
                    } else {
                        value(e.val);
                    }
                    shouldIgnore = false;
                }
            });
        }

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            if (changeListener) changeListener.dispose();
            $(element).select2("destory");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: To follow ko practice, the content of changeListener should go to `valueSelect2.update` callback. http://jsfiddle.net/huocp/8N3zX/10/