# Select 2 deferred Loading data with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ui-select2

I've a knockout.js view which shows 20 rows of data. each row has a select 2 control bound with knockout.js. (Below you can see my bindinghandler)

Now each select 2 points to the same array of items . This array has about 10.000 entries. This results in a slowdown of the whole page (about 2-3 seconds freezetime)

I'm thinking about to only load the options when the user clicks the row.  like this:

```
 self.setSelectedRow = function (entry) {
        entry.options(allOptions);
        var value = entry.intialValue;
        entry.StationdId(value);
    };
```

After this the select 2 is expandable and i can choose options, but the initialvalue is not applied.
Any hints on what i'm doing wrong?

Binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function () {
            $(el).select2('destroy');
        });

        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);

        $(el).select2(select2);
    }
};
```

Comment: You only have an `init` function in your binding handler, so you don't get the updates. I think you need to implement the [`update` function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) as well

Comment: @GôTô Why don't you add this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Peter I wasn't sure enough :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i'll give it a shot. btw i'm quite new to knockout, can you give me an codeexample how the update function should look like  ? many thanks in advance. PS add it as an answer  if its not workin i will tell you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding handlers usually have two functions:

- An `init` function that is called when the binding is created (note that it *can be called more than once* as it is called each time you create/recreate the binding -- example: when node is in an `if` binding). This function should contain the code to setup the binding (which ou did well)
- An `update` function which is called every time the observables inside your binding markup change. Note that this function is also called on init (right after the `init` function) so in certain cases you won't need an `init` function.

More info in the [`custom` binding doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

In your case, I think the `init` function is fine.

The problem is nothing is set up to handle the changes on your observables.

You can add an `update` function that would look like this (*untested*):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        /* your code is fine */
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);
        $(el).select2(select2); //update the select2
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a very outdated `knockout` version, I think your binding syntax is wrong.

This part is wrong:

```
var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
  select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);
```

If you read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html
the correct way to use `allBindingsAccessor` (it should be named allBindings anyway) is

```
var select2 = allBindingsAccessor.get('select2') || {};
```

**BUT even this is unnecessary**, valueAccessor gives you what is under current binding (`select2`).

So just try this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function () {
            $(el).select2('destroy');
        });

        $(el).select2(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

Comment: you may have problem to sync StationdId and options with the UI. You can try the `select2` binding I created in another answer, as `<select data-bind="options: options, valueSelect2: StationdId"></select>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712462/select2-allowclear-and-knockout-js/24729557#24729557

Comment: Although you may be right, we don't have the markup and so you don't know how the binding is done. It could be something like `data-bind="select2: { someProperty }, select2OtherProperty: 'true'"` just like [`clickBubble`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-4-preventing-the-event-from-bubbling) is not inside `click` binding

Comment: @GôTô, true. What I can tell from the author's `init` implementation is that it doesn't seem to use any other binding property rather than `select2`.

Comment: BTW, fixed a typo in the answer, it should be `allBindingsAccessor.get('select2')`.